# Plone taking a long time to respond to byte-range request

Tags: apache, plone, zope, mod-proxy, mod-cache

We have two recently upgraded Plone 4.3.2 instances behind a haproxy load balancer which itself is behind Apache.

We limit each Plone instance to serving two concurrent requests using haproxy configuration.

We recently encountered an issue whereby a client sent 4 byte-range requests in quick succession for a PDF that each took between 6 and 8 minutes to get a response.  This locked up all available requests for 6 minutes and so haproxy timed out other requests in the queue.  The PDF is stored an ATFile object in Plone which I believe should have been migrated to blob storage in our recent upgrade.

My question is what steps should we take to prevent a similar scenario in the future?

I'm also interested in:

- how to debug why the byte-range requests on an otherwise lightly loaded server should take so long to respond
- how plone.app.blob deals with byte-range requests
- is it possible to configure Apache such that byte-range requests are served from its cache but not from the back-end server

As requested here is the haproxy.cfg with superfluous configuration stripped out.

```
global
    maxconn         450
    spread-checks   3

defaults
    log             /dev/log local0
    mode            http
    option          http-server-close
    option          abortonclose
    option          redispatch
    option          httplog
    timeout connect 7s
    timeout client  300s
    timeout queue   120s
    timeout server  300s

listen cms 127.0.0.1:18181
    id 3
    balance leastconn
    option          httpchk
    http-check      send-state
    timeout check   10s

    acl cms_edit url_dom xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    acl cms_not_ok nbsrv() lt 2
    block if cms_edit cms_not_ok

    server cms_instance1 app:18081 check downinter 10s maxconn 2 rise 1 slowstart 300s
    server cms_instance2 app:18082 check downinter 10s maxconn 2 rise 1 slowstart 300s
```

Comment: Show us your haproxy configuration settings.

Comment: Have you issued or simulated a similar request to a bare ZServer instance, rather than apache+haproxy front-end?  Process of elimination will give you (and those who might help you) a better picture.

Comment: I haven't tried replicating solely through Zserver but I haven't yet been able to replicate through the entire stack.  I have checked the logs and the 4 troublesome requests all hit Zope.

Comment: I added the haproxy configuration.  This configuration hasn't changed in over a year.  I'm suspicious its much more likely an issue with Zope as that did recently change.

Answer (score 0):

You can install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.LongRequestLogger and check its log file to see where the request gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted to disable byte-range requests to the back-end Zope server.  I've added the following to the CMS listen section in haproxy.

```
reqidel ^Range:.*
```